# Binding loop detected for property "foreground"

Tags: c++, qt, qml, yocto, qqmlengine

My application is running very well inside Ubuntu operational system. But when I try to run it inside the Yocto using Boot2Qt it throws the following error message:

```
QML ToolBar (parent or ancestor of Material): Binding loop detected for property "foreground"
```

Here is a spinet of my code that throws this error.

```
 Page{
    id: mainPage
    anchors.fill: parent
    visible:  true
    header: ToolBar{id: toolBarHeader
        parent: mainPage
        height: root.toolBarHeight
        anchors.left: parent.left
        anchors.top: parent.top
        anchors.right: parent.right
        anchors.topMargin: 0
        anchors.leftMargin: 0
        Material.background: Material.color(Material.BlueGrey, functionsJS.toolBarIntensity())
```

Here is the result that I'm getting: nasty application response:
[image: nasty application response]

Trying to figure out what is going on. I've done this:

```
 Page{
    id: mainPage
    anchors.fill: parent
    visible:  true
    header: ToolBar{id: toolBarHeader
        parent: mainPage
        height: root.toolBarHeight
        anchors.left: parent.left
        anchors.top: parent.top
        anchors.right: parent.right
        anchors.topMargin: 0
        anchors.leftMargin: 0
        background: Rectangle{anchors.fill: parent; color: "red"}}
```

End now, I'm getting this: Maybe problem with material?:
[image: Maybe problem with material?]

Comment: What is `functionsJS.toolBarIntensity()`?

Comment: @JarMan just returns a number, if it's in dark-mode is 8 and if it's not is 2

Comment: I found the best way to debug a binding loop is to look at it through GammaRay. It's a free tool that you can use to introspect running Qt applications. Select the item you have the binding on in the Quick Views tools, then look at the Bindings tab in your right pane. You can expand the tree of properties being used in the binding to follow why it is a loop. Get it from here: https://github.com/KDAB/GammaRay

Comment: Hi, @André I've heard about it. I'll try it. thanks